# Videos are not working in Ubuntu 20.04.2.0

Tags: mp4

Ever since I upgraded my Ubuntu to 20.04.2.0, I cannot open any videos or Mp4 files. I looked up similar complains here and found some answers about installing some packages but  did not work, are there any problems with 20.04.2.0 and video players. I did open the video but only could here the content and cannot see anything, any help?.

Comment: Do you have codecs installed?

Comment: can you start the player from terminal? `xdg-open path to your file.mp4` and show us the output from terminal?

Comment: No, I don't have codecs installed and that is the error message that shows up when I try to open videos.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost impossible to answer without some debug info, errors etc. I suggest installing VLC and before you attempt to play video and open Tools > Messages and set Verbosity to Debug. Also, you can add set a log file if you wish.
If you think it's something related to 20.04 then you can try a live CD for another version prior to upgrading (if an option).

Comment: I installed VLC and I can view videos now, but my video player itself is not accepting videos and asking for installing codecs.

Comment: So, why no just use VLC? Its a really good app. If you prefer your video player why not install the codecs its requesting?

Comment: Actually, I could not install codecs, and tried the instructions given here and stuck in the terminal.

Comment: Could you add the output seen in the terminal when trying to add codecs?

Comment: Thanks mike I downloaded another video player and having my videos working well.